# How to add digit separating in joomla's virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm really in need of digit separating for joomla's virtuemart 2.
Use case:
Using some currencies like Iranian Rials, prices for usual tablets are about 7000000 Rials, which is hard to realize the price at first look. My ideal is 7,000,000 Rials number formatting.
I've found so many solutions for java script, but I'm so good at PHP language programming.
Thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be write your own customization for the price separation in VM2.x

Just login with Admin user

```
Components -> VM -> Configuration -> Currencies -> Click on Currency name.
```

you will get following options.

Currency Symbol ,Decimals , Thousands Separator ,Positive Format,Negative Format

Hope it solve your problem..